# Why, in Civicase, is 'other relationships' purely additive & why do they show up on every subsequent case?

Tags: civicase, 4.6

If I manually add someone to 'Other Relationships' in Civicase by using 'Add members to Case Resources', then that someone then shows up in ALL cases under 'other relationships' - not just for the client where I added the contact.  And, there is no way of removing them to correct the situation - I've looked at the database tables and can't find where this info is stored.  For example I added Joe Bloggs in 'Other Relationships' using 'Add members to Case Resources' - and now 'Joe Bloggs' shows up in ALL cases in 'other relationships' - but if I look at Joe Bloggs contact records it shows no relationships at all. Is this a bug or a WAD?  And how can I remove these contacts?

Answer (score 4):

I found the answer here [in an old forum posting](https://forum.civicrm.org/index.php?topic=35204.0)  Civicase creates a group called 'Case Resources' into which it drops any contact you add (as described above).  So to remove these from all cases you just edit this group.  Phew!  Wasted an hour or so, but now a little wiser!

Comment: Where to find "Case Resources" group? I've looked in Contacts-> Manage Groups but nothing. Used all the search options but still come up a blank.